# Doing a commentary of a proof (if a poset has a unique minimal and that minimal is not the smallest, then the poset is infinite)

Tags: logic, proof-writing, proof-explanation

The initial proposition was: "If a subset of a partially ordered set has exactly one minimal element, must that element be a smallest element?"

And here is a proof: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2280977/1184854

But this doesnt directly proof the proposition right? They prove a little bit different proposition.

Here is my commentary of the proof:

The proposition is of the form $P\rightarrow Q$, where $P=$poset has unique minimal element $x$, $Q=x$ is the smallest

This proof states that the proposition would be true if the poset was a finite set.

So the new proposition is of the form: $Y\rightarrow(X\rightarrow Q)$,
$Y=$poset is finite
$X=$poset has a unique minimal $x$
$Q=$the minimal $x$ is the smallest

The proof proves the contrapositive, so they assume a poset $P$ has a unique minimal element $x$, and they also assume $x$ is not the smallest. Now they need to prove that the poset is not finite.
e.g $X\land\neg Q\rightarrow \neg Y$

They introduce a subset $S\subset P$ that contains all incomparable elements with $x$. And since $x$ is not the smallest element, this subset is not empty. Then they assume that $S$ has a minimal element $y$, and prove that this leads to a contradiction with the fact that $x$ is the unique minimal of $P$. So then they conclude that $S$ has no minimal element, which means that $S$ has an infinite descending chain, which means that $P$ is infinite.

Is this "commentary" valid? e.g are the things that i have said correct?

Comment: Robert Israel did not claim to prove the statement in the OP. He was merely pointing that the statement *would be true* if you add the assumption that the set is finite. This is very clear from the way the post is phrased. It starts out stating that exact point. If he were claiming to prove the statement in the OP, you would have had to read carefully to pick up on this assumption of finiteness. It would not be clearly spelled out as an additional assumption at the start of the post,